# Can 2 smartphones be connected via microUSB-USB cable + OTG USB female 2 microUSB for ADB to work?

Tags: usb-connection-mode

re.:
Can 2 smartphones be connected via microUSB-USB cable + OTG USB female 2 microUSB  for ADB to work?

There are USB C <> USB C cables on a market, found none microUSB <> microUSB

So not sure if using USB hub as a middle-man can work or should I use 2 OTG  microUSB <> USB female cables,  interconnected by USB2USB cable

--
Ok, started with microUSB 2 USB cable inzserted into OTG USG female 2 microUSB cable to get microUSB 2 microUSB cable.

Should I enable USB debugging on both devices ?

I connect from Android 5.0.2 smartphone to  Android 4.2 tablet

On tablet , the only selectable application for usb debugging is called
com.android.partnerbrowsercustomizations.example

just enabled it on tablet

run on smartphone in Terminal Emulator
adb devices

daemon started successfully
starting it now on port 5038

List of devices attached

none
adb list devices
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32

and help list

no IP address on tablet
device not connected

is OTG cable not fit for ADB ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a USB cable if the objective is to use adb on one phone to access another? Just setup adb in wireless mode on one phone, connect both phones to same wireless network, then use another phone with adb client to access the first phone.

Comment: @Firelord Robert from another thread, advised me to start ADB connection with USB cable than switch to WiFi mode,  since USB cable connection to be mandatory
BTW
I would prefer WiFi Direct communication, no router involved, if supported by 2 Android smaretphones.
This is my first ADB try, so I follow advices provided by others.

Comment: @Firelord  
"Wireless ADB on non-rooted Devices

Note: This requires a one time use of a USB cable, so have one handy. 

from
https://beebom.com/how-use-adb-wirelessly-android-device/

Comment: @Firelord
"Wireless ADB on Rooted Devices

If you’re on a rooted device, you don’t need a USB cable. Not even once.

from
https://beebom.com/how-use-adb-wirelessly-android-device/